# How do I make a JTextArea fill up a JPanel completely?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jtextarea

I'd like my JTextArea component to completely fill up my JPanel. As you can see here, there is some padding around the JTextArea (which is colored red with an etched border) in this picture:

[image: Image of program below.]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Create JComponents and add them to containers.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("Hello world!");
    panel.add(jta);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(panel);

    // Modify some properties.
    jta.setRows(10);
    jta.setColumns(10);
    jta.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

    // Display the Swing application.
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mukul Goel I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `FlowLayout`, which will only give your `JTextArea` the size that it needs. You can either try fiddling with the min, max, and preferred size of the `JTextArea`, or you can use a layout that will give your `JTextArea` as much room as possible. `BorderLayout` is one option.

The default layout of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, so to use that you would need to **not** set it specifically. The default layout of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, so you do need to set that one specifically. It might look something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // Create JComponents and add them to containers.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("Hello world!");
    panel.add(jta);
    frame.add(panel);

    // Modify some properties.
    jta.setRows(10);
    jta.setColumns(10);
    jta.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

    // Display the Swing application.
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: @JohnH There are a ton of layouts. GridLayout also comes to mind. Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: plus one but please (you are execelent poster everywhere) 1. why frame.setSize(200, 200); if is there jta.setRows(10)/setColumns(10); :-), 2. or missing there a JScrollPane (why not to guide the OP:-)

Comment: @mKorbel I just took the basics of the OP's code, which I assume is just example code anyway. You have to set the size of the JFrame, either directly or by a call to pack(). And adding a JScrollPane goes outside the bounds of this question and would just be confusing, imho, so I that stuff out.